# Find Last inserted value from kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I hit a API that gives me some number every time. I have to write a Kafka producer to generate continuous stream of numbers using this API output.

For ex: I hit API I got number 450 then I have to check what was last inserted number in kafka broker(suppose it was 200). Then in my producer I have to generate numbers from 201,202...450 and insert as separate message in kafka.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `KafkaConsumer.seek` after describing the offsets to seek to the last offset -1 to get the most recent message.

**However**, there is a possibility that some producer has pushed a message between your queries.

I suggest you not use Kafka for maintaining the latest number, and rather Redis or some other KV-store (a **KTable** might work too)